# Not able to save values into existing li and span tags in JS

Tags: javascript

The code is to create a to-do list using item and quantity and I have used bootstrap components for buttons and list view button not able to save the newly added items into the existing list view created in the html file.

```js
var item=document.getElementById("first");
var quantity=document.getElementById("second");
var button=document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary")[0];
var ul=document.querySelector("ul");

function nameLength(){
  return item.value.length;
}

function quantityLength(){
  return quantity.value.length;
}

function createListElement(){
  var li=document.createElement("li");
  var span=document.createElement("span");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.value));
  span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(quantity.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  ul.appendChild(span);
  item.value="";
  quantity.value="";
}

function addListAfterClick(){
  if(nameLength()>0 && quantityLength()>0){
    createListElement();
  }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event){
  if((nameLength>0 && quantityLength>0) && event.keyCode==13){
    createListElement();
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click",addListAfterClick);

item.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);
quantity.addEventListener("keypress",addListAfterKeypress);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<input  id="first" type="text" placeholder="enter item">
<input id="second" type="number" placeholder="enter quantity">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
<ul class="list-group">
   <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
     <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill"></span>
   </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mea n by "save"? Like refresh the page and it is still there?

Comment: Are you talking about `state` or are you talking about `database`?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to have a `<span>` be a child of a `<ul>`.

Comment: If you provide us sample HTML, then we can verify your problem.

Comment: I mean adding the new values from item and quantity to the li and span class that I have used in the HTML file.

Comment: `ul.appendChild(li);
ul.appendChild(span);`First fix that

Comment: do you want to have the content you just added to be still there when you hit F5? :D

Comment: No Lol, I just want the content to appear in  the bootstrap list and span tags that I have used in the html file.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

> You have already included jquery in the html. Using of jquery will
>   reduce you code by lot. I would recommend to you `jquery` if not using
>   with any js framework.

```js
var item=document.getElementById("first");
var quantity=document.getElementById("second");
var button=document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary")[0];
var ul=document.querySelector("ul");

function nameLength(){
  return item.value.length;
}

function quantityLength(){
  return quantity.value.length;
}

function createListElement(){
  var li=document.createElement("li");
  var span=document.createElement("span");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.value));
  li.className = 'list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center';
  span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(quantity.value));
  span.className = 'badge badge-primary badge-pill';
  li.appendChild(span)
  ul.appendChild(li);
  item.value="";
  quantity.value="";
}

function addListAfterClick(){
  if(nameLength()>0 && quantityLength()>0){
    createListElement();
  }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event){
  if((nameLength>0 && quantityLength>0) && event.keyCode==13){
    createListElement();
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click",addListAfterClick);

item.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);
quantity.addEventListener("keypress",addListAfterKeypress);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<input  id="first" type="text" placeholder="enter item">
<input id="second" type="number" placeholder="enter quantity">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
<ul class="list-group">    </ul>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```